# Python: Solving knapsack optimization with a genetic algorithm?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, knapsack-problem

currently I am trying to wrap my head around the best way to accomplish what I am doing. I have the following pandas df.

```
    Player  Pos Salary  My Proj
0   James Harden    PG/SG   10600   51.94472302
1   Jose Juan Barea PG/SG   4200    22.20823452
2   Stephen Curry   PG/SG   8700    42.95809374
3   Eric Gordon     SG      5400    27.45218158
4   Nikola Vucevic  C       7400    37.00103015
5   Wilson Chandler SF/PF   4900    24.83866589
```

This goes on for roughly 200 players every day. I need to run an optimization to fill up to 20 lineups on draftkings that follow the following constraints:

Under $50,000
Using 1 PG, 1 SG, 1 SF, 1 PF, 1 C, 1 G, 1 F, and 1 UTIL

As you can see most players can fill multiple positions in a single lineup denoted by the "/" character in the position column. The G position can be filled with either a PG or a SG and the F position can be filled with a SF or PF with the UTIL position accepting all positions.

At first I looked into using a knapsack brute force approach which seemed to be the simplest but there are literally trillions of combinations, so this would take an outrageous amount of time without ever really doing what I truly want.

Instead I decided to try using a genetics approach as I have been watching many lecture videos on this and think it is a great idea for this problem. However, I don't know how to set this problem up in a general 1/0 knapsack approach as there are numerous things I need to include. In a typical knapsack approach you just have a weight and a value. My weight and values are the players salary and their projected score. However I have to include the position of the player in here as well, which can be 1 or sometimes 2 different possibilities for one player.

Hopefully this makes sense, and I am basically looking for some sort of insight on how to begin tackling this task within Python 3. Thanks ahead of time for anything you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good start:

Fully understand the basics of a Genetic Algorithm, good example [here](https://lethain.com/genetic-algorithms-cool-name-damn-simple/).

The beauty of genetic algorithms are that once you define how to evaluate fitness, everything else falls into place on its own.  You could start with completely random items and over successive generations it will become orderly.  The lineup and knapsack problem are very, very similar if you approach it the right way.  You already know how many items can fit (head-start); you now just have to select which ones and that is where the GA comes in.

Think of these steps:

1. Create your population(random lineups)
2. Check the fitness of the population, are the positions filled, salary less than the maximum, etc
3. Evolve the population while grading the lineups
4. Continue with new generations until you are satisfied.